# I can't refresh the data from the button on LWC component

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter, lwc-dom

I created this component and the idea is to get all the files and put in one place. But I also need to add a refresh button, so it could return and new files that were uploaded.

But I am not sure how to add I am trying to use the refreshApex but is not refreshing the UI on the way I was expecting. The button **refreshCloudFiles**

How could I make this works?

HTML

```
 <template lwc:if={hasData}>
      <lightning-accordion allow-multiple-sections-open>
        <template for:each={accordionData} for:item="sobject">
          <lightning-accordion-section key={sobject.name} name={sobject.name} label={sobject.name}>
            <template for:each={sobject.folders} for:item="folder">
              <lightning-accordion-section key={folder.name} name={folder.name} label={folder.name}>
                <div class="image-gallery">
                  <template for:each={folder.photos} for:item="photo">
                    <template lwc:if={photo.isPDF}>
                      <div class="image-column" key={photo.photoName}>
                        <p><a href={photo.photoURL} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
                          <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/87/PDF_file_icon.svg" alt={photo.photoName} class="image-pdf"/>
                          </a></p>
                        
                        <p class="auto">{photo.photoName}</p>
                      </div>
                    </template>
                    <template lwc:elseif={photo.isDOC}>
                      <div class="image-column" key={photo.photoName}>
                        <p><a href={photo.photoURL} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
                          <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fb/.docx_icon.svg" alt={photo.photoName} class="image-pdf"/>
                          </a></p>
                        
                        <p class="auto">{photo.photoName}</p>
                      </div>
                    </template>
                  <template lwc:else>
                    <div class="image-column" key={photo.photoName}>
                      <p><a href={photo.photoURL} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
                        <img src={photo.photoURL} alt={photo.photoName} class="image"/>
                        </a></p>
                      
                      <p class="auto">{photo.photoName}</p>
                    </div>
                  </template>
                    
                  </template>

                </div>

              </lightning-accordion-section>
            </template>
          </lightning-accordion-section>
        </template>
      </lightning-accordion>
    </template>
```

Javascript

```
import {LightningElement, api, wire, track} from 'lwc';
import {refreshApex} from '@salesforce/apex';
import getPhoto from '@salesforce/apex/displayCloudFilesController.getPhoto';

export default class AccordionEx extends LightningElement {
@api recordId;

@track hasData = true;
@track errorData;

@track showSpinner = false;
@track accordionData = [];
@track wiredPhotoData = [];

@wire(getPhoto, {caseId:'$recordId'})
 wiredPhotos({error, data: dataPhoto}){
    this.wiredPhotoData = dataPhoto;
    console.log(dataPhoto);
    if (dataPhoto) {
      
      this.buildFileData(dataPhoto);

    } else if (error) {
        this.errorData = error;
      
    }
}

refreshCloudFiles (event) {

        this.showSpinner = true;
        let timer = window.setTimeout(() => {

          try {
            refreshApex(this.wiredPhotoData);
            console.log('success');
           } catch (ex) {
            // Handle the exception here or log it for debugging purposes.
            console.error('Error in refreshCloudFiles:', ex);
           } finally {
            window.clearTimeout(timer);
            this.showSpinner = false;
           }
            
        }, 9000)
        
        console.log(this.wiredPhotoData);
  }

  // This will build the Map of File that will be show in the accordion in the following Structure SObject -> Folder -> File
  buildFileData(dataPhoto){

    let photoMap = new Map();
    console.log(dataPhoto);     
    dataPhoto.forEach((item) => {
        const objectSF = item.ObjectSF;
        const folder = item.Folder;

        const photo = {
          photoURL: item.PhotoURL,
          photoName: item.PhotoName.length > 39 ? item.PhotoName.substring(0, 39)+ '...': item.PhotoName,
          photoFullName: item.PhotoName,
          isPDF: item.isPDF,
          isDOC: item.isDOC,
          fileType: item.FileType
        };

        //Structure SObject -> Folder -> File (in case the Sobjec is not on the Map)
        if (!photoMap.has(objectSF)) {
            photoMap.set(objectSF, []);
        }

        const objectFolders = photoMap.get(objectSF);
        let folderObj = objectFolders.find((obj) => obj.name === folder);

        if (!folderObj) {
          folderObj = {
            name: folder,
            photos: []
          };
          objectFolders.push(folderObj);
        }

        folderObj.photos.push(photo);
      });
      this.accordionData = Array.from(photoMap, ([name, folders]) => ({ name, folders }));

      if(this.accordionData.length > 0){
        this.hasData = true;

      }
      else {
        this.hasData = false;
      }

  }
```

APEX Class

```
public with sharing class displayCloudFilesController {
    

    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<FileCloud> getPhoto(String caseId){

        List<FileCloud> fileCloudList = new List<FileCloud>();
        String goCaseId = '';
        Id aOppId;
        List<TVA_CFB__Cloud_Files__c> CloudFiles = new List<TVA_CFB__Cloud_Files__c>();

        try {

            Case cs = [Select Id,Opportunity__c, Project_QA_Review__c, Order__c  From Case where Id =: caseId];


            Id orderId = cs.Order__c;
            Id qaReviewId = cs.Project_QA_Review__c;
            Id opportunityId = cs.Opportunity__c;
    
            Id recordTypeGoCase = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('GO Case').getRecordTypeId();


            List<Case> goCases = [Select Id from Case where Order__c =:orderId AND RecordTypeId =:recordTypeGoCase limit 1];

            if(goCases.size()> 0){
                goCaseId = goCases.get(0).id;
            }

            TVA_CFB__CloudFiles_Settings__c credentials = TVA_CFB__CloudFiles_Settings__c.getInstance (UserInfo.getUserID ());
            Map <String, TVA_CFB__Cloud_Files_Region_Endpoints__c> regionEndPoints = TVA_CFB__Cloud_Files_Region_Endpoints__c.getAll ();
            Map <ID, String> fileURlsMap = new Map <ID, String> ();
           
            String queryCloudFiles = 'SELECT ID, Name, TVA_CFB__Bucket_Name__c, TVA_CFB__Region__c, TVA_CFB__Folder__c,'+
            'TVA_CFB__File_type__c, TVA_CFB__External_File_name__c, Opportunity__c, GO_Case__c, QA_Review__c, Service_Appointment__c, Order__c '+
            'FROM TVA_CFB__Cloud_Files__c WHERE ';

            if(goCaseId != null || opportunityId != null || qaReviewId!= null || orderId != null){
                    queryCloudFiles = queryCloudFiles + '(';


                if(orderId != null){
                    queryCloudFiles = queryCloudFiles + '(Order__c=: orderId AND TVA_CFB__Folder__c IN (\'Fotos Fertige PV-Anlage & Module\','
                    +'\'Invoices\', \'Fotos bereits vorhandener Schäden\', \'Fotos DC-ÜSS\', \'Fotos Erdung\', \'Fotos Gesamtbild der Elektro-Anlage\', \'Fotos Kabelführung\','
                    +'\'Fotos Notstrombox\', \'Fotos Optimiererplan/Stringplan\', \'Fotos - Sonstige\', \'Fotos Speicher\', \'Fotos Unterkonstruktion\', \'Fotos Wallbox\','
                    +'\'Fotos Wechselrichter\', \'Fotos Zählerschrank\', \'Abnahmeprotokoll\'))';
                } 

                if(goCaseId != null) {
                    
                    queryCloudFiles = queryCloudFiles + ' OR (GO_Case__c =:goCaseId AND TVA_CFB__Folder__c IN (\'Confirmation of registration with Marktstammdatenregistrierung (Auszug MaStR)\', \'Wiring Plan (Schaltplan)\','
                        +'\'Application for registration with grid operator (Inbetriebsetzungsantrag Zählerwechsel)\', \'Commissioning protocol (Inbetriebsetzungsprotokoll E8)\','
                        +'\'Inbetriebssetzungsprotokoll Speicher E3\', \'MaStR Batteriespeicher\'))';
                }
                if(opportunityId != null){
                    queryCloudFiles = queryCloudFiles + ' OR ( Opportunity__c =: opportunityId AND TVA_CFB__Folder__c = \'Signed Offer\')';
                } 
                if(qaReviewId != null){
                    queryCloudFiles = queryCloudFiles + ' OR (QA_Review__c =: qaReviewId AND TVA_CFB__Folder__c IN (\'Signed Offer\', \'SEPA\', \'Abtretungsanzeige\')) ';

                } 
                    
                    queryCloudFiles = queryCloudFiles + ')';

                    System.debug(queryCloudFiles);

                    CloudFiles = Database.query(queryCloudFiles);

                    System.debug(CloudFiles);
                    
            } else{
                return null;
            }
            

            if(CloudFiles.size() > 0){

                for(TVA_CFB__Cloud_Files__c fcloud:CloudFiles){

                    System.debug(fcloud);
                    Map <String, String> cloudFileDetails = NEW Map <String, String> ();
                        if (fcloud.TVA_CFB__Bucket_Name__c != NULL && fcloud.TVA_CFB__Region__c != NULL) {
                        cloudFileDetails.put ('ID', fcloud.ID);
                        cloudFileDetails.put ('bucket', fcloud.TVA_CFB__Bucket_Name__c);
                        cloudFileDetails.put ('region', fcloud.TVA_CFB__Region__c);
                        cloudFileDetails.put ('fileName', fcloud.Name);
                        cloudFileDetails.put ('fileType', fcloud.TVA_CFB__File_type__c);
                        cloudFileDetails.put ('s3FileName', fcloud.ID+'.'+fcloud.TVA_CFB__File_type__c);
                        cloudFileDetails.put('folder', fcloud.TVA_CFB__Folder__c);
        
                        if (fcloud.TVA_CFB__External_File_name__c != null) {
                        String fileName = fcloud.TVA_CFB__External_File_name__c;
                        fileName = EncodingUtil.URLEncode (fileName , 'UTF-8');
                        fileName = fileName.replace ('+', '%20');
                        fileName = fileName.replace ('%2F', '/');
                        cloudFileDetails.put ('externalFileName', fileName);
                        cloudFileDetails.put ('s3FileName', fileName);
                        }
                        fileURlsMap.put (fcloud.Id, TVA_CFB.amazonS3Authentication.generateMultipleViewLinks (credentials,
                        regionEndPoints,
                        cloudFileDetails,
                        2000, // URL expiration time in seconds.
                        NEW Map <String, TVA_CFB__CloudFiles_MIME_Types__c> ()));
                        
                        FileCloud newFileCloud = new FileCloud();
                        newFileCloud.folder =  fcloud.TVA_CFB__Folder__c;
                        newFileCloud.PhotoURL = fileURlsMap.get(fcloud.id);
                        newFileCloud.PhotoName = fcloud.Name;
        
                        newFileCloud.isPDF = fcloud.Name.contains('.pdf') ? true: false;
                        newFileCloud.isDOC = fcloud.Name.contains('.docx') || fcloud.Name.contains('.doc')? true: false;
                        newFileCloud.ObjectSF = '';
                        System.debug(fcloud);
                        System.debug(fcloud.id);
                        
                        if(fcloud.Opportunity__c != null && fcloud.TVA_CFB__Folder__c == 'Signed Offer'){
        
                            newFileCloud.ObjectSF = fcloud.Opportunity__c.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName();
                            fileCloudList.add(newFileCloud);
                        }
                        if(fcloud.QA_Review__c != null && (fcloud.TVA_CFB__Folder__c == 'SEPA' || fcloud.TVA_CFB__Folder__c == 'Abtretungsanzeige'
                        || fcloud.TVA_CFB__Folder__c == 'Signed Offer') ){
                            newFileCloud.ObjectSF = fcloud.QA_Review__c.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName();
                            fileCloudList.add(newFileCloud);
                        }
        
                        if(fcloud.Order__c != null && (fcloud.TVA_CFB__Folder__c == 'Fotos Fertige PV-Anlage & Module' 
                        || fcloud.TVA_CFB__Folder__c == 'Invoices' || fcloud.TVA_CFB__Folder__c == 'Fotos bereits vorhandener Schäden'
                        || fcloud.TVA_CFB__Folder__c == 'Fotos DC-ÜSS' || fcloud.TVA_CFB__Folder__c == 'Fotos Erdung'
                        || fcloud.TVA_CFB__Folder__c == 'Fotos Gesamtbild der Elektro-Anlage' || fcloud.TVA_CFB__Folder__c == 'Fotos Kabelführung'
                        || fcloud.TVA_CFB__Folder__c == 'Fotos Notstrombox' || fcloud.TVA_CFB__Folder__c == 'Fotos Optimiererplan/Stringplan'
                        || fcloud.TVA_CFB__Folder__c == 'Fotos - Sonstige' || fcloud.TVA_CFB__Folder__c == 'Fotos Speicher'
                        || fcloud.TVA_CFB__Folder__c == 'Fotos Unterkonstruktion' || fcloud.TVA_CFB__Folder__c == 'Fotos Wallbox'
                        || fcloud.TVA_CFB__Folder__c == 'Fotos Wechselrichter' || fcloud.TVA_CFB__Folder__c == 'Fotos Zählerschrank'
                        || fcloud.TVA_CFB__Folder__c == 'Abnahmeprotokoll' )){
                            newFileCloud.ObjectSF = fcloud.Order__c.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName();
                            fileCloudList.add(newFileCloud);
                        }
                        if(fcloud.GO_Case__c != null && (fcloud.TVA_CFB__Folder__c == 'Confirmation of registration with Marktstammdatenregistrierung (Auszug MaStR)'
                        || fcloud.TVA_CFB__Folder__c == 'Wiring Plan (Schaltplan)'
                        || fcloud.TVA_CFB__Folder__c == 'Application for registration with grid operator (Inbetriebsetzungsantrag Zählerwechsel)'
                        || fcloud.TVA_CFB__Folder__c == 'Commissioning protocol (Inbetriebsetzungsprotokoll E8)'
                        || fcloud.TVA_CFB__Folder__c == 'Inbetriebssetzungsprotokoll Speicher E3)'
                        || fcloud.TVA_CFB__Folder__c == 'MaStR Batteriespeicher'
                        )){
                            
                            newFileCloud.ObjectSF = 'Go Case';
                            fileCloudList.add(newFileCloud);
                        }
        
                        System.debug(newFileCloud.ObjectSF);
        
                    }
                }


            }
            

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
        }


        System.debug(fileCloudList);
        return fileCloudList;
    }

    public static string getSobjectName(Id recordId){

        return recordId.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName();
    }

    public class FileCloud {
        @AuraEnabled public String ObjectSF{get;set;}
        @AuraEnabled public String Folder{get;set;}
        @AuraEnabled public String PhotoURL{get;set;}
        @AuraEnabled public String PhotoName{get;set;}
        @AuraEnabled public String FileType{get;set;}
        @AuraEnabled public Boolean isPDF{get;set;}
        @AuraEnabled public Boolean isDOC{get;set;}

       
    }
  
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the template I see no reference to `refreshCloudFiles` method, anyway `refreshApex` needs the whole object returned by the wired adapter, as stated in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/apex-result-caching.html), not just the `data` property.

```js
@wire(getPhoto, {caseId:'$recordId'})
wiredPhotos({error, data: dataPhoto})
```

Here you used the [destructing assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to extract the property `error` and `data`, therefore you lost the reference to the needed object.
You should change it to:

```js
showSpinner = false; // no need to use @track here
wiredPhotoData; // no need to use @track here

@wire(getPhoto, { caseId: '$recordId' })
wiredPhotos(fileCloudList) {
    this.wiredPhotoData = fileCloudList;
    const {error, data: dataPhoto} = fileCloudList;
    console.log(dataPhoto);
    if (dataPhoto) {
      this.buildFileData(dataPhoto);
    } else if (error) {
        this.errorData = error;
    }
    this.showSpinner = false; // turn off the spinner once the data have been refreshed
}
```

Please note that `@track` is not needed for primitive. If a property is used in the template, it's [already reactive](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/reactivity-fields.html).

Keep in mind that the `refreshApex()` function returns a Promise, so you should use a `then()` block to work with the refreshed data and a `catch()` to handle errors. Moreover if you want to stop the spinner only once the new data are available, `this.showSpinner = false` should be in the wired function.

```js
refreshCloudFiles() {
    this.showSpinner = true;
    setTimeout(() => {
        refreshApex(this.wiredPhotoData)
            .then(() => {
                console.log('refreshApex successfully run');
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log('refreshApex error:', error);
            });
    }, 9000);
}
```

Currently I see no reason for the `setTimeout()` function. 9s is a big delay.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add in the code here in the topic is on my code.

     `<lightning-button label="Refresh Cloud Files" onclick={refreshCloudFiles} variant='neutral' ></lightning-button>`

Comment: @FabioNiglio Could you please edit the question adding that button? Any reason to run the `refreshApex` after 9s?

Comment: I was just testing I reduced to 2 seconds!

Comment: It worked. Now I understand that in my case I have to bring the whole Wrapper object created on the Apex for data Binding!

Thank youu!